# How to load/save a txt file to richtextbox according to specific date from monthcalendar

Tags: c#

i have the date selected in a textbox

```
// Create a SelectionRange object and set its Start and End properties.
SelectionRange sr = new SelectionRange();
sr.Start = DateTime.Parse(this.richTextBox1.Text);
sr.End = DateTime.Parse(this.textBox3.Text);

/* Assign the SelectionRange object to the 
SelectionRange property of the MonthCalendar control. */
this.monthCalendar1.SelectionRange = sr;
this.richTextBox1.LoadFile(@"C:\a.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

and i would like to load a specific text file for each date(example 25/5/2013 --2552013.txt

how can i do it?
i am thinking to take out the / from

```
 this.richTextBox1.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

and later load it from the local folder with a button click, and save it with another button.

Comment: How can you do what? Load a file? Have you done your research on this prior to asking this question? What did you find difficult when searching for this?

Comment: Do you have problem about removing '/' chars? or loading/saving file?

Comment: both are problems to me, i don't know to remove chars and load/save file

Answer (score 0):

You can use Replace method for removing "/" chars like

```
string fileName = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace("/","") + ".txt";
```

an alternative way for creating file name from datetime

```
DateTime startDate = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date;

string day = startDate.Day > 9 ? startDate.Day.ToString() : "0" + startDate.Day.ToString();
string month = startDate.Month > 9 ? startDate.Month.ToString() : "0" + startDate.Month.ToString();
string year = startDate.Year.ToString();

string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}.txt", day, month, year);
```

another way that easy and fast by @Patrick

```
string fileName = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToString("ddMMyy") + ".txt";
```

and you can save or load file to RichTextBox like

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile(fileName);
richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName);
```

Comment: why not use date.ToString("ddMMyy")?

Comment: You are right @Patrick. Actually I thought that it can be different culture and wrote alternative way but yours is basic, easy, fast.

Comment: You could add the extension of the file as well in the string.Format call - `string.Format("{0:ddMMyy}.txt", date);`

Comment: btw, if you do want to extract day for instance, there's no need to do the `startDate.Day > 9` check, just use `startDate.ToString("dd");`..

Comment: thank you for your answers, i have the fileName formatted as I wanted, but i cannot load it, my code is richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\\'" + fileName +"'"); where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you see file at this ("C:\\'" + fileName +"'") path? How do you save? Can you share code?

Comment: string fileName = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToString("ddMMyy") + ".txt";
            fileName = "C:\\" + fileName;
richTextBox1.LoadFile(fileName);
now I have the wanted path with the code above, but it crashes when I try to load it, the last line of the code is highlighted due to some error "File format is not valid"

Comment: I strongly recommend in cases like this you do yyyy-MM-dd (or yyyyMMdd) to get the right sort order.

Comment: @vkon I think it is about write and read rights. I tried and got same error. If you try to use another path (eg. "D:\\") it works, of course you don't have to use "C:\\".

Comment: @vkon if you don't specify a disk letter, the file will be saved to **Application Startup Path**.